# Find user dynamically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, find

** I want to create a function that accepts any data like id, email, etc., and finds the user based on the input passed to it. **

ex:

```
const user = async(input)=>{
    const result = data.findOne({input}); //whatever the input I passed I want the user
    return result;
}
```

should I Pass the key with input like (input, key)??
so I need one common function to find the user data dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know ahead of time what fields the data might be found in, use `$or` to check them all:

```
data.findOne({$or: [
    {id: input},
    {email: input},
    {username: input}
]})
```